# Как передать из контроллера переменную в site/index.php?

Tags: yii2, yii

Пробую так, но данные не передаются
\controller

public function actionIndex()

```
{
    $categories = Categories::find()->asArray()->all();
    print_r($categories);
    return $this->render('index', compact('categories'));
  }
```

index.php

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $prod) :?>
                    <div class="product">
                        <a href="#" class="product_img">
                            <img src="images/<? echo $prod['img'];?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. А Вы уверены, что запрос возвращает не пустой ответ? И как Вы в index выводите данные?

Comment: @slo_nik
 Да, на других страницах отображается нормально.
Оно не выводит результата print_r

Comment: Если print_r() пустой, то значит запрос ничего не возвращает. И поэтому в вид не передаётся

Comment: @slo_nik: Но в запросе есть возвращаемые данные, только не пойму почему на других страницах выводится результат, а в index нет

Comment: В print_r() есть результат запроса? Как Вы в index выводите данные?

Comment: @slo_nik Да, есть.    <?php foreach ($categories as $prod) :?>

Comment: Ну а в теле foreach() как Вы выводите?

Comment: дополните свой вопрос кодом

Comment: @slo_nik исправил

Comment: Вы уверены что именно так? <? echo $prod['img'];?> Может лучше будет использовать нормальные теги <?php ?>

Comment: @slo_nik, до того места не доходит, оно ругается на аргумент foreach (видимо потому что он пустой)

Comment: уберите print_r()

Comment: @slo_nik Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Код в контроллере вполне рабочий. Только print_r() уберите. И ещё раз проверьте, что Вам возвращает запрос, что именно содержится в $categories. В index используйте полные теги php, закройте кавычку и тег img.  Если ошибка останется, то ищите причину где-то ещё, возможно что-то мешает. И попробуйте сделать проверку if() else

Comment: @slo_nik okay, спасибо

Comment: Вы именно в body выводите $categories? Залейте куда-нибудь index.php и покажите.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return $this->render('index', ['categories' => $categories]);
```